# Accessing a file after creating it

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I have the following code that creates an XML file in memory, updates it and then adds it to a form library.

```
// Creates a new XML document in memory
XmlDocument newCRF = new XmlDocument();

// Loads an existing XML file into that in-memory document
newXMLdoc.Load("Template.xml");

// Write the XML file to a document library
using (SPSite newSite = new SPSite("http://sharepoint/newsite"))
{
    using (SPWeb newWeb = newSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList newLibrary = newWeb.Lists["Test Library"];
        byte[] xmlData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newXMLdoc.OuterXml);

        // Save file to form library
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xmlData))
        {
            SPFile newFileInLibrary = newLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add("Filename.xml", ms);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I access the 'newFileInLibrary' object so that I can make changes to it's properties (such as "Created By")?

Comment: Check the FileInfo class

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `SPListItem` object by using this code :

```
    // Save file to form library
    SPFile newFileInLibrary = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xmlData))
    {
        newFileInLibrary = newLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add("Filename.xml", ms);
    }
    SPListItem fileItem = newFileInLibrary.Item;
    DoSomethingWith(fileItem["Created"]);
```

Ps: did you considered posting on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting the following from the 5th line in your code: "A local variable named 'newFileInLibrary' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'newFileInLibrary', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.

I had considered posting this to the SharePoint site but I thought it was more of a language issue rather than something specific to SharePoint.

Comment: Did you noticed I removed the type before the `newFileInLibrary` variable within the `using` block ? In fact, I scoped the variable to the outer scope (your method), but I assign it inside the using block.